# Does ag-grid support Vue.js with the server side model?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm new to ag-grid, and note that the examples for the server side model:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model/

are only available in JavaScript, Angular and React.

Is it just the examples that are missing, or will the server side model not work with Vue.js at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine in Vue.js, there's just not been an example written for it.

I can tell this by comparing the JavaScript and React examples. I understand both of them well, and there's not much React specific stuff in the React example. You can just port it to Vue.js and use the standard `ag-grid-vue` component.

If you need a quote: https://www.ag-grid.com/best-vuejs-data-grid/

> ### ag-Grid VueJS Features
>
> Every feature of ag-Grid is available when
>   using the ag-Grid VueJS Component. The VueJS Component wraps the
>   functionality of ag-Grid, it doesn't duplicate, so there will be no
>   difference between core ag-Grid and VueJS ag-Grid when it comes to
>   features.